# json array disply in <li> using angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, restangular

JSON array I am getting after get API call,   I am getting following json response.

```
{
    "reactions":[{
        "severity":{
            "label":"Severe"
        },
        "label":"Skin Rash"
    }],
    "audit":{
        "source":"medicare",
        "createDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z",
        "update‌​Date":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z",
        "version":"1"
    },
    "label":"Other - IODINE",
    "ended":"2007-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
    "started":"1993-01-01T00:00:00-05:00‌​",
    "date":"2015-03-02T18:37:42Z"
}".
```

And I need to just display only

`":[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}]"` in li tag. 
How can I do that ?

I need to populate this json array in `<li>` in html5. How can I do it? I am using restangular.:

Angular JS file:

```
Restangular.one('APIName', Parameter_to_api).get().then(function (result) {

  $scope.datalist= result;
}
```

HTML file

```
<ul class="links">
   <li ng-repeat="data in datalist"></li>                   
</ul>
```

Comment: This is my HTML file:                                                                                     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="links">
                                    <li ng-repeat="data in datalist"></li>
                 </ul>
       </div>
      </div>

Comment: `How can I do it` ...  which part of the process are you having problems with? Question is not very clear

Comment: @charlietfl: after making API call I am getting response as a json array. Which I have mentioned in the question. I need to populate that json array in to <li> tag. How can I do that. Json response format I have mentioned in question. How I am trying to do that I have explained. Sorry.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code posted.  However, I also don't see any mention of what is expected, or what is being seen instead of expected.

Comment: You are already doing it, you just need to set datalist to whichever array you want. Right now it's being set to an object. So change it to $scope.datalist = result.data1 or something

Comment: What is in the arrays and what is expected output result? You simply need to use expressions to print the data

Comment: I think you may need to review [ask].  This is the 3rd question you have presented which is receiving overwhelmingly negative responses.  It will be important for you to clarify the questions you ask a bit more, or risk having your asking rights taken away.

Comment: @charlietfl: I have add additional question. Can you please look at it ?

Comment: still not clear what expected results is. You probably need to spend more time studying angular tutorials such as the one in documentation site

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.datalist = {
    data1: [2, 3, 4],
    data2: [6, 7, 8, ],
    data4: [9, 10, 12]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <ul class="links" ng-repeat="data in datalist">
      <li ng-repeat="i in data">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @sylwester: Additional question. Now req. change. I am getting following json response. "{"reactions":[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}],"audit":{"source":"medicare","createDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z","updateDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z","version":"1"},"label":"Other - IODINE","ended":"2007-10-28T00:00:00-04:00","started":"1993-01-01T00:00:00-05:00","date":"2015-03-02T18:37:42Z"}". And I need to just display ":[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}]" in li tag. How can I do that ?