# How to populate values in <li> using ng-repeat from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

As this AngularJS is new to me,  I was trying to populate dropdown value of the list using JSON and ng-repeat. I saw ng-option for **"select"** but nothing as such for **"li"**

Below is the piece of JSON file I am trying to read from:

```
[
{
    "header": {
        "name": "Electronics",
        "subHeader": {
            "childHeader": [{
                    "name": "Mobiles",
                    "view": "#mobile"
                }, {
                    "name": "Tablet",
                    "view": "#tablet"
                }, {
                    "name": "Television",
                    "view": "#television"
                }, {
                    "name": "Headphones",
                    "view": "#headphones"
                }]
        }
    },
        "name": "Men",
        "subHeader": {
            "childHeader": [{
                    "name": "Shirts",
                    "view": "#shirts"
                }, {
                    "name": "T-Shirts",
                    "view": "#tshirts"
                }, {
                    "name": "Jeans",
                    "view": "#jeans"
                }, {
                    "name": "Trousers",
                    "view": "#trousers"
                }]
        }
    }

]
```

The JS file is as below and is working fine:

```
var mainAngular = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
mainAngular.controller('headerCategoryController', function($scope,$http) {
var hCat=  "./customAngular/headerCatalogue.json";
$http.get(hCat).success(function(response){
    $scope.categories=response;
});
});
```

I want it in to be generated in below format:

```
            <div class="headerMenu" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electronics<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="index_category.htm">Mobiles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="product.htm">Tablets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="cart.htm">Televisions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="checkout.htm">Headphones</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Men<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="index_category.htm">Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="product.htm">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="cart.htm">Trousers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="checkout.htm">Jeans</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
```

What I am doing right now is this:

```
<div class="headerMenu" ng-controller="headerCategoryController">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="category in categories">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{category.header.name}}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li ng-repeat="val in category"><a href="{{val.header.subHeader.childHeader.view}}">{{val.header.subHeader.childHeader.name}}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

I refered "[json array disply in <li> using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111199/json-array-disply-in-li-using-angular-js)" link for this but still no luck. Can someone please help !

Comment: First of all fix your JSON, you can't go any further without it.

Comment: The JSON you provided seems to be valid JSON, but you have repeated keys inside objects, try changing the subheader elements to an array or at least an object with different keys. Just try pasting your JSON to a linter like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: your "subHeader" section is an array . User this syntax subHeader:[ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of the JSON you provided:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Electronics",
        "subHeader": [
            {
                "name": "Mobiles",
                "view": "#mobile"
            },
            {
                "name": "Tablet",
                "view": "#tablet"
            },
            {
                "name": "Television",
                "view": "#television"
            },
            {
                "name": "Headphones",
                "view": "#headphones"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Men",
        "subHeader": [
            {
                "name": "Shirts",
                "view": "#shirts"
            },
            {
                "name": "T-shirts",
                "view": "#tshirts"
            },
            {
                "name": "Trousers",
                "view": "#trousers"
            },
            {
                "name": "Jeans",
                "view": "#jeans"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Notice how the headers and subheaders are arrays.

Next, The view had to change a little bit too:

```
<div class="headerMenu" ng-controller="headerCategoryController">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{category.name}}<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="subheader in category.subHeader"><a ng-href="{{subheader.view}}">{{subheader.name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9UN6DjEuSZCtBjc1SOhK?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a drop down you can do something like this as well

```
<select ng-options="optionslist">
   <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```